# Improve PDF display performance on the screen using BLOB and iFrame

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, pdf, iframe

I have a function in Javascript that receives a parameter with bytes and in the function I convert the parameter `result` to `Uint8Array` and then display the `iFrame` with the content in the "`DisplayPDF`" element.

Sometimes it loads fast and but when you have a long byte parameter it takes 10 seconds to load. There is something in this function that can be done to display this faster.

```
 function GetPdf(result) {
            const bytes = `${result}`;
            var stringToArray = bytes.split(/[\s,]+/);
            var pdfBytes = Uint8Array.from(stringToArray);

            const bl = new Blob([pdfBytes], {
                type: "application/pdf"
            });
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(bl);
            
            $("#DisplayPDF").html(
                $('<iframe>', {
                    src: url + '#toolbar=0&&scrollbar=1',
                    width: '600px',
                    height: "600px"


                })
            );
        }
```

View

```
 <div id="DisplayPDF" style="float: right ; height:20vh; margin-top:12px"></div>
```